# How does SFTP transfer files when SCP cannot?

Tags: macos, command-line, ssh, sftp, scp

While at work, I am restricted from using `scp` to copy files from a remote server to my machine and when I try, the operation always times out. However, when using an FTP client that supports`sftp`, the files copy without issue, on the same port.

The way I understand `scp` and `sftp` is they both use SSH, so why does one work where the other does not?

Comment: "_The way I understand scp and sftp is they both use SSH, so why does one work where the other does not?_" No, you are listing three different protocols.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/1080547/23133

Comment: SFTP is an "upgrade" to SCP,  and largely replaces it, so many SFTP services allow fallback to the SCP protocol, but the admin may not have allowed SCP. SCP and SFTP are different protocols so unless the server supports both, only the accepted client protocols may be used.

Comment: If you are really getting timeout when connecting, then indeed, it should not matter. if you are connecting with `scp` or `sftp`, as both connect to the SSH port 22 . Show us an exact error message, or ideally an output of `scp -v ...` and `sftp -v ...`.